# How to get the HTTP method of a REST request

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jax-rs

In case of an exception in my Java REST application I would like to log various information on causing HTTP request.

I can obtain the URI of the request and the HTTP headers via context injection

```
@Context
private UriInfo uriInfo;

@Context
private HttpHeaders headers;
```

But how can I obtain the HTTP method (GET, PUT, ...)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I use Jersey. Don't know if this applies for you but ... :

```java
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;    

@Context final HttpServletRequest request
```

The `Request` class has the method `getMethod()`. It returns the used HTTP method.

Answer (score 0):

You are usually limiting the rest methods to one http method

```
 @GET
 @Produces("text/plain")
  public String getClichedMessage() {
    // Return some cliched textual content
    return "Hello World";
 }
```

Comment: Yes, usually. But I think the question here applies for the few other cases

Answer (score 0):

Jersey is irrelevant (following the most upvoted answer.)

HttpServletRequest class of Java Servlet API has `getMethod()` method that returns the name of the HTTP method (`GET, POST, PUT`, etc).

But you do not always need it. For example, if you are in servlet, you have doGet, doPost methods.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
   //method is POST
}
```

protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
//method is GET
}

But you do need it, for example, in the filter:

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, 
          FilterChain chain) throws ServletException, IOException {

     String method = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getMethod();

}
```

Speaking of the REST, different REST frameworks may provides various ways to obtain the HttpServletRequest object.